# Prevent MS SQL Studio from connecting to multiple database systematically

Tags: sql-server

I have a team who have access to Production and QA databases. And many a times we end up connecting to both instances and firing QA query in PROD. I know the best practice needs to be inculcated amongst the people to not open multiple instance at the same time, but once in a while one of us inadvertently ends up running query from QA to PROD. So i am looking for a feature in SQL studio that i can leverage to restrict connecting to multiple instance in SQL Studio at a time.

Revoking access is not an option.

Comment: This is an education problem, nothing more. Your DBA's/Developers need to be vigilante with what they are doing. If they can't be trusted then they should lose their rights to deploy to Live; problem solved (as they get an error when they try to deploy to the wrong  place). You could also look into getting add-ins for SSMS, some of which give visual indicators for what instance you're connected to. For example, my tabs are different colours depending on the instance (and sometimes database) I am connected to; but tool recommendation isn't on topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If they can't be trusted I'd be inclined to revoke their access. Or at least make them RDP to a bastion server which would be the only place they could access PRD from so they can't do it directly from their desktops.